# get the web page source with the rendered html from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

If I use this

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://test.net");
```

I am able to use the agility pack to scan the html and get most of the tags that I need but its missing the html that is rendered by the javascript.

My question is, how do I get the final rendered page source using c#. Is there something more to the WebClient to get the final rendered source after javascript is run?

Comment: I doubt you can do this with C# alone.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML Agility Pack alone is not enough to do what you want,  You need a javascript engine as well.  To do that,  you may want to check out something like Geckofx, which will allow you to embed a fully functional web browser into your application, and than allow you to programatically access the contents of the dom after the page has rendered.

http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap a browser in your application.

You are in luck!  There is a .NET wrapper for WebKit.  http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebBrowser Class from System.Windows.Forms.

```
using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser()) 
{
    //Code here
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx